# Besides black magic, what could cause inclusion of js/css files in their containing html document when fetching a page over http vs https?

Tags: javascript, html, http, caching, https

I'm stuck on this one for a while with absolutely no clue.

I'm working on a site which needs to be loaded over http. It's made up of gadgets (HTML files) including css/js dependencies. A central plugin does the loading of dependencies and inserts them into the DOM.

Say I have this in gadget:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Core Gadget</title>

    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:700,400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/normalize/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/jquery-mobile/jquery-mobile.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/fontawesome/css/fontawesome_import.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../lib/fontawesome/css/fontawesome.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gadget_core.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gadget_core_custom.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="gadget_core_themes.css" />

    <script src="../lib/rsvp/rsvp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../lib/renderjs/renderjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../lib/uri/uri.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../lib/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../lib/jquery-mobile/jquery-mobile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="gadget_core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
...
```

If I load the page over **https:**, all files are loaded separately (what I'd expect). However if I load the same page over **http**, all CSS and JS except for jQuery Mobile are injected into the html page with no http request showing up in the inspector, thus breaking the page.

**Question**:
(Besides black magic), what other things could I explore to figure out what is happening?

I moved the whole page to a clean server (same result) and think I have deactivated all caching I could find in the browser (running FF33 on Linux Ubuuntu)

Try yourself: Load [broken http](http://softinst54091.node.vifib.com/public/app/manifest/gadgets/gadget_index.html) - all js/css will be inline(d) except jQuery Mobile. Load [works https](https://softinst54091.node.vifib.com/public/app/manifest/gadgets/gadget_index.html) - site loads properly.

Thanks for some clues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inlining is usually done by a proxy server (often a transparent one) between the browser and the server and is most common on mobile (3G, 4G, etc) Internet connections in an attempt to improve performance by reducing the number of HTTP requests (at a cost of reducing caching).

Since HTTPS is encrypted, it can't be transparently proxied without browsers throwing security alerts.

The URL you provide does not inline the content when I access it on my wired network connection so the problem is most likely with your ISP and not the site.